# Upload any documents into telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I would like to upload any documents into telegram bot.

For example:

> **The user** type `/sendpic`, and then **the bot** waits for uploading a
>   document by the user.

Here the code:

```
import config
import telebot

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True,content_types=['document'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id

        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src = 'B:/' + message.document.file_name;
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

        bot.reply_to(message, "Saved that.")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

But this function don't have any reaction. Can you help me , in what am I wrong?
I was searching for answers here, but all examples I saw that it downloads **FROM** a bot, but I need upload **INTO** the bot

Comment: Are you sure that the path to the file you want to upload really starts with `B:/`? If you're on Windows, `B:` drive is typically missing nowadays.

Comment: Also, have you tried debugging the code and checking which of several function used behaves in an unexpected way?

Comment: @yeputons      Oh, I thought that I will save it into 'B:' but upload from a user. Am I wrong?Yes, I was trying to debug it , I'm using Pycharm, but can't achieve a step fro uploading. Might be I can't do it in PyCharm... I don't know really:(